# I am not able to pass my nested object from app.js to EJS file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am finding for a particular ID in Workspace collection

```
Workspace.find({_id: requestedWorkspaceID} ,function(err, foundList) {
if(!err) {
  if(foundList) {
    console.log(foundList);
    console.log(foundList.files);
    // res.render("workspace.ejs", {files: obj.files});
  }
}
```

})

[Here is the picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOFrw.png)

```
console.log(foundList);
```

Its output is

```
[{
_id: new ObjectId("628e3a08f95d0929fab8ad25"),
name: 'Workspace 1',
files: [
  {
    filename: 'Default File 1',
    filecontent: 'This is an example',
    _id: new ObjectId("628e3a08f95d0929fab8ad22")
  },
  {
    filename: 'Default File 2',
    filecontent: 'This is an example',
    _id: new ObjectId("628e3a08f95d0929fab8ad23")
  },
  {
    filename: 'Default File 3',
    filecontent: 'This is an example',
    _id: new ObjectId("628e3a08f95d0929fab8ad24")
  }
],
__v: 0 }]
```

I have used

```
require('util').inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null
```

that is why I am getting full visible object in my output. Before using require('util')..
my output was like this..

```
[{
_id: new ObjectId("628e3a08f95d0929fab8ad25"),
name: 'Workspace 1',
files: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
__v: 0
```

}]

```
console.log(foundList.files);
```

Its output is `undefined`

**I am not able to view my `files` (array of objects). I need to render the data present in `files` array of objects through EJS file. That is why I need to pass this whole `foundList` to `workspace.ejs`.**
When I am passing it, i am getting an error in `workspace.ejs` that `files` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has one object inside. You should choose this object first and then get its `files` property:

```
console.log(foundList[0].files)
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    filename: 'Default File 1',
    filecontent: 'This is an example',
    _id: '628e3a08f95d0929fab8ad22'
  },
  {
    filename: 'Default File 2',
    filecontent: 'This is an example',
    _id: '628e3a08f95d0929fab8ad23'
  },
  {
    filename: 'Default File 3',
    filecontent: 'This is an example',
    _id: '628e3a08f95d0929fab8ad24'
  }
]
```